# Windows task scheduler is not running in Windows server 2012 when trigger option is set as Startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

I have a task scheduler to execute a batch file on windows start up. I have the following setup in task scheduler,

**Trigger** - At startup

**Action** - to execute a batch file

**Security options** - Run whether user is logged on or not

When i reboot the machine, the task is not getting triggered and the status is ready. The same is working fine when i run it on demand.

My scenario is to run the batch file at the system startup (user will not log on to the machine) and the batch file should open a separate command prompt.

The above is working when executing the task **on demand** and not while during **startup**.

Comment: The program will be invisible if *Run If logged on or not* is set. This is by design. Also you can't interact with a user's screen till they logon.

Comment: What does the batch file do?

Comment: the batch file will start selenium grid hub and node. I want the command to be visible, because when i run the selenium scripts i want the real browser to open and view the script execution

Answer (score 0):

Following two steps are important

1 Configure for **Windows 10** is important
[image]

2 Make sure all the checkboxes are unchecked as shown below, **this is important**
[image]

Refer [this](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Invoking-Using-Windows-Task-Scheduler-At-Startup) for more details